# MongoDB not authorized for query admin.system.users

Tags: mongodb, authentication, nosql

I am bit new to MongoDb and I am using MongoDb v.2.4.Here the problem is that when I run the mongod with --auth parameter, even after authenticating I am not able to perform simple operations such as "show users". But works fine if I run mongod without --auth parameter.

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth("dbadmin","mypassword")
1
> show users
**Thu Feb 27 16:50:17.695 error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on admin.sys
tem.users", "code" : 16550 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128**
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you should to run mongod on localhost without `--auth` and create user with necessary [roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/security/#role-management-methods) that you needed. In your case you should add `userAdminAnyDatabase` or `userAdmin` role. Than you could run mongod with `--auth` and authenticate by this user for have remote access to `system.users` collections.
You could read about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control).

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm! Actually I had assigned  dbAdminAnyDatabse role to the admin.That's where I missed it I guess.

Answer (score 10):

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.grantRolesToUser("your_admin_name" ,[ "root"])
```

This command will give you all privileges on any db as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think your admin user has not been configured as mongo says.

I have just answer a question in another thread with explanation step by step :
[Not authorized for query on admin.system.namespaces on mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704703/not-authorized-for-query-on-admin-system-namespaces-on-mongodb/25085830#25085830)

try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not for the OP, but for those of you landing here on an internet search for

```
Failed: error counting admin.system.users: not authorized on admin to execute command { count: "system.users", query: {}, $db: "admin" }
```

The answer, most likely, is that you need to specify the database name in the connection string. For example, in my case, I was doing a `mongorestore`, like so

```
mongorestore --uri=mongodb+srv://[username]:[password]@[mongo-server] --dir=[backup-file]
```

And what I needed to do was

```
mongorestore --uri=mongodb+srv://[username]:[password]@[mongo-server]/[database-name] --dir=[backup-file]
```

The same thing would apply to a `mongodump`. The point is that it tries to connect to the `admin` DB by default, and that might not be what you're trying to do.