# MongoError: not authorized on.....Can't run mongodb projects on localhost anymore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, windows-10

There must have changed something on my dev inviroment but I do not understand what it was. I use mongodb for all my projects and everything worked well until now. When I try to run any project on localhost I get the following error. When I change the connection string to a remote db it works fine, so there must be somethin wrong with my local installation.

```
MongoError: not authorized on ngfullstack1-test to execute command { delete: "users", deletes: [ { q: {}, limit: 0 } ], ordered: true }
at Function.MongoError.create (m:\Websites\Evalu\Angular\yo\ng-full-stack\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at commandCallback (m:\Websites\Evalu\Angular\yo\ng-full-stack\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1154:66)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
at [object Object].Callbacks.emit (m:\Websites\Evalu\Angular\yo\ng-full-stack\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:119:3)
at [object Object].messageHandler (m:\Websites\Evalu\Angular\yo\ng-full-stack\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:295:23)
at Socket. (m:\Websites\Evalu\Angular\yo\ng-full-stack\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:285:22)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Comment: You took no effort in finding solution, If you did the first search of `MongoError: not authorized to execute command` gives you a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB not authorized for query admin.system.users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067612/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-admin-system-users)